# Windows 8 lower left, right click and/or windows-X dissabled, any ideas?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

I have lost the ability to use the old style start by right-clicking in the lower left corner and using the windows-x shortcut.

This was after uninstalling a ton of things I migrated from Windows 7 and believe it would be a setting changed, but could be something was removed? Unfortunately, I used the windows 8 upgrade and do not have a disk.

Comment: What exactly happens when you press Win+X ?

Comment: It only un-selects what I was on, but otherwise it does nothing. For example if Icon highlighted, that is no longer the focus.

Comment: Do you use a 3rd party Startmenu in Windows 8? They often disable those options.

Comment: @magicandre1981 as far as I know unless inadvertently have not altered that. But like I said, I uninstalled a lot of stuff. This included many Microsoft products. It is an older desktop using dual Xeon processors and seemed to be very slow once I jumped to 8. I removed or turned off Visual Studios, IIS features and others so I can get Apache and an open source stack to not conflict. Everything seems to be much faster and working normal otherwise.

Comment: Use ShellExView to disable all (non MSFT) shellextensions. http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html

Comment: @Shane: Also try `sfc /scannow` from an elevated/admin command prompt.